# How to submit Stripe card info for review page after entering payment info on previous page

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I have a multi-step Stripe donation payment form in React with the following pages:

- donation amount
- contact information and address
- payment information, where the user enters their credit card number
- review

Here are the mockups. (I'm not sure if it's actually feasible to show the last four digits of the card number, but that's another question.)

[image: Payment page and Review page]

We can submit the payment successfully if we omit the review page and submit the donation on the Payment page. But if we add in the review page, and have the button to submit the payment there, the payment fields are no longer on-screen, so Stripe is not able to get it. One solution might be to keep the payment fields on the screen but hidden with CSS, but I'm unsure whether this would pose security issues. I'd rather not store the credit card information in React state for security/liability reasons.

We are using the `useElements()` hook of Stripe, and then passing `const card = useElements().getElement("cardNumber")` to `stripe.createPaymentMethod`. `card` is null because it is no longer on the page, so this fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `cardNumber` element gets removed from the DOM when React re-renders between pages. Two possible solutions:

1. Hide the element rather than unmounting it. Setting the CSS `display` property to `none` will hide the element rather than outright removing it.
2. Create the PaymentMethod before the components are unmounted. When "continue" is clicked, create the PaymentMethod and store the resulting object in your state before submitting the actual payment.